# Can't separate returned JSON output to convert it into new PHP variable

Tags: php, json, api

This question has been answered in specific ways in other places, however I need to work out a general rule / way to take a person ID from an API POST, and then use that to move that newly created person into another area of the site.

```
$timestamp = date("y-d-m G:i:s");

$client = new http\Client;
$request = new http\Client\Request;

$body = new http\Message\Body;
$body->addForm(array(
  'name' => $_POST['email'],
  'email' => $_POST['email'],
  'page-location' => $_POST['page-location'],
  'active_flag' => '1',
  'add_time' => $timestamp
), NULL);

$request->setRequestUrl('https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/persons');
$request->setRequestMethod('POST'); 
$request->setBody($body);

$request->setQuery(new http\QueryString(array(
  'api_token' => '472320163fd56c5371797bd54b91e7e5b04cd7a9'
)));

$client->enqueue($request)->send();
$response = $client->getResponse();


echo $response->getBody();
```

The JSON returns something like this:

```
{"success":true,"data":{"id":20,"company_id":506319,"owner_id":{"id":709354,"name":"Christian Bahrendt","email":"cb@nowdiscover.co","has_pic":true,"pic_hash":"41678d0bdf1124ecc6a88b01ffb360a7","active_flag":true,"value":709354},"org_id":null,"name":"tester@tester.com","first_name":"tester@tester.com","last_name":null,"open_deals_count":0,"closed_deals_count":null,"participant_open_deals_count":0,"email_messages_count":0,"activities_count":null,"done_activities_count":null,"undone_activities_count":null,"reference_activities_count":null,"files_count":null,"notes_count":0,"followers_count":0,"won_deals_count":0,"lost_deals_count":0,"active_flag":true,"phone":[{"value":"","primary":true}],"email":[{"label":"","value":"tester@tester.com","primary":true}],"first_char":"t","update_time":"2015-08-03 21:57:10","add_time":"2015-03-08 23:57:09","visible_to":"3","picture_id":null,"next_activity_date":null,"next_activity_time":null,"next_activity_id":null,"last_activity_id":null,"last_activity_date":null,"org_name":null,"cc_email":"nowdiscovergmbh@pipedrivemail.com","owner_name":"Christian Bahrendt"},"related_objects":{"user":{"709354":{"id":709354,"name":"Christian Bahrendt","email":"cb@nowdiscover.co","has_pic":true,"pic_hash":"41678d0bdf1124ecc6a88b01ffb360a7","active_flag":true}}}}
```

And I need to convert the ID into $newUserID.

How would/should I do that in PHP!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access the data in the **JSON** easily, you need to decode it to either object or associative array using **json_decode**  (http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and then access the data within as you usually do for objects/arrays:

```
$object = json_decode($response->getBody());
$newUserID = $object->data->id;

$array = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
$newUserID = $array['data']['id'];
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks.